# django_filters and drf_yasg is not compatible

Tags: python, django, django-filter, drf-yasg

I am developing a project where I am using django_filters and there are some views where I have filters and apparently I have problems because of that. This is the message

```
UserWarning: <class 'apps.tenant_apps.orders.api.views.TotalProductsByOrderStateAPIView'> is not compatible with schema generation
```

and comes from django filters. I am following the documentation to the letter but I see no support for this warning. What should I do?

django_filters docs: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
drf_yasg docs: https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
class ProductByCategoriesListView(TenantListApiViewMixin):
    # 2. Listar productos por categoría o categorías
    # http://example.localhost:8000/api/products/list/category/?categories=Electr%C3%B3nica,Ropa%20y%20Accesorios,Ropa,Calzado,Muebles%20y%20Decoraci%C3%B3n
    serializer_class = ProductByCategorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        categories = self.request.query_params.get('categories', '').split(',')
        queryset = []

        for category in categories:
            # Utiliza Q objects para construir las condiciones OR
            q_objects = Q()
            q_objects |= Q(
                channelproduct_product__productcategory_channelproduct__channel_category__category__icontains=category)
            q_objects |= Q(
                channelproduct_product__productcategory_channelproduct__integration_category__category__icontains=category)

            # Filtra ProductModel con las condiciones OR
            products = ProductModel.objects.filter(
                q_objects).distinct().values_list('name', flat=True)

            if products:
                queryset.append({
                    'category': category,
                    'products': list(products)
                })

        return queryset

    @swagger_auto_schema(tags=['Product'])
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I expected this view to be placed in the Products tag but it sent me a warning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqmC2.png)